# How to search for particular strings between commas in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table column that contain strings seperated by `,` like so

```
Algebraic topology,Riemannian geometries
Classical differential geometry,Noncommutative geometry,Integral transforms
Dark Matter
Spectral methods,Dark Energy,Noncommutative geometry
Energy,Functional analytical methods
```

I am trying to search for the MySQL row that has a string between comma, for example if I was search for `Noncommutative geometry`, I want to select these two rows

```
Classical differential geometry,Noncommutative geometry,Integral transforms
Spectral methods,Dark Energy,Noncommutative geometry
```

This is what I tried

```
SELECT * FROM  `mytable` WHERE  ``col` LIKE  '%Noncommutative geometry%'
```

which works fine, but there problem is that if I was searching for `Energy` I want to select the row

```
Energy,Functional analytical methods
```

but my code gives the two rows

```
Energy,Functional analytical methods
Spectral methods,Dark Energy,Noncommutative geometry
```

which is not what I am looking for. Is there a way to fix this so that it only finds the rows that have the string between commas?

Comment: how about `SELECT * FROM  mytable WHERE  col LIKE  ',%$searchterm%,';`

Comment: What about `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Energy', col) > 0`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: "string between commas???"..do you want only row which contais Dark Energy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give these a try, using the [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator:

```
SELECT * FROM  `mytable`
WHERE  `col` REGEXP  '(^|.*,)Noncommutative geometry(,.*|$)'

SELECT * FROM  `mytable`
WHERE  `col` REGEXP  '(^|.*,)Energy(,.*|$)'
```

The expression being used (`'(^|.*,)$searchTerm(,.*|$)'`) requires the search term to be either preceded by a comma or the beginning of the string, and followed by either a comma or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
SELECT * FROM  `mytable` WHERE  `col` LIKE  '%,$yourString,%'
                         or `col` LIKE '$yourString,%'
                         or `col` LIKE '%,$yourString'
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if I was searching for `Energy` it will list the row `Spectral methods,Dark Energy,Noncommutative geometry`